# How to pivot 2 columns into 1 row, with row 1 as column labels and row 2 as values

Tags: oracle, pivot, pivot-table

I have 2 columns of data with the following layout:

```
-------------
|Name|Count |
-------------
|Val1|Val1_2|
|Val2|Val2_2|
|Val3|Val3_2|
|Val4|Val4_2|
|Val5|Val5_2|
```

However i'm unsure how to use the pivot function, to get it to look like this:

```
------------------------------------
|Val1  |Val2  |Val3  |Val4  |Val5  |
------------------------------------
|Val1_2|Val2_2|Val3_2|Val4_2|Val5_2|
```

I understand some sort of aggregate function must be used however i want val1_2 and etc to remain the same.

Any ideas? I think this may be simple however i can't quite grasp it.

Comment: are you using oracle or mysql?

Comment: Thanks Lelio for the edit. - Oracle is the version im using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have only 5 column you could use  a fake aggregation function and case

```
      select  min(case when  Name ='Val1' then count end ) Val1
       , min(case when  Name ='Val2' then count end ) Val2
       , min(case when  Name ='Val3' then count end ) Val3
       , min(case when  Name ='Val4' then count end ) Val4
       , min(case when  Name ='Val5' then count end ) Val5 
     from my_table
```